# Segmentation fault when transforming document with Xalan

Tags: c++, xalan

I'm using Xalan-C++ to do an XSLT transformation and I'm getting a segmentation fault in this code:

```
XalanTransformer evalTransformer;
evalTransformer.setUseValidation(false);
evalTransformer.transform(*(xmlDoc.getDocumentBuilder()), rule_, resultStream);
```

Previously, I use this code to initialise a XalanDocumentBuilder:

```
// Create a XalanTransformer.
XalanTransformer        theXalanTransformer;

// Get a document builder from the transformer...
docBuilder_ = theXalanTransformer.createDocumentBuilder();
```

and then create an XML document with `docBuilder_`, so `xmlDoc.getDocumentBuilder()` (which just returns `docBuilder_`) should return a valid pointer.

If I attach gdb to the running process this is the first few lines of the stack trace:

```
#0  0x0a2de894 in ?? ()
#1  0x0514f8d9 in amxalanc_1_6::XalanTransformer::doTransform () from /usr/lib/libamxalanc1_6.so
```

The `transform()` method was working with a simple output stream, but when I changed the 1st parameter it now fails.  I've use the document builder object to successfully create an XML document.  Any ideas why I would be getting a segmentation fault within the Xalan code?

Comment: Is the pointer returned from `xmlDoc.getDocumentBuilder()` pointing to valid memory?

Comment: Can you try to "setUseValidation(true) and rerun it?"

Comment: I tried it, but got the same result.

Comment: The big thing I see in your question is the phrase "should return a valid pointer". Have you actually verified that it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `theXalanTransformer` is initialised in another function.  It is constructed for the sole reason of creating an XML document in memory using `docBuilder_`. `theXalanTransformer`'s destructor would be called at the end of that function, and it destroys `*docBuilder_` implicitly at this time also, since `*docBuilder_` is created using `theXalanTransformer`. Later `evalTransformer` is used to do the transformation, but `*docBuilder_` has already been destroyed.

I didn't realise `*docBuilder_` would be destroyed when `theXalanTransformer` is destroyed. When I kept `theXalanTransformer` in memory long enough to do the transformation the result was successful. I suppose it would be even better to use one `XalanTransformer` to create the XML document and do the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I am preparing for an official release of Xalan-C 1.11.

Can you post your issue to the Apache Jira for XALANC so this issue can be tracked?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANC

I also have an Apache committer's website

http://www.apache.org/~shathaway

Thanks for posting to the mailing list

c-users@xalan.apache.org

Sincerely,
Steven J. Hathaway
Xalan Documentation Project

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. You can see the resolution in my answer below. Perhaps it could be documented more clearly that when a `XalanTransformer` is destroyed its associated `XalanDocumentBuilder` is also wiped out?

Comment: Actually, it does say in the documentation for [`XalanTransformer.createDocumentBuilder`](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/apiDocs/classXalanTransformer.html#a17): "The XalanTransformer instance owns the document builder and will delete it when the XalanTransformer instance goes out of scope."

However, I first looked at the documentation for the destructor, which is blank.

Answer (score 1):

The verson 1.6 of Xalan-C is old.  The latest stable version is 1.10.
There have been many segment fault pointer fixes resolved by the upgrade.
The new version 1.11 being prepared for release has many more segment fault
pointer fixes resolved.

If this is new code, you should make sure that your Xerces and Xalan
libraries are initialized before doing any useful work.

http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-c/usagepatterns.html#xalan

Sincerely,
Steven J. Hathaway
Xalan Documentation Project

Comment: Unfortunately it's not (easily) practical to use a newer version of Xalan-C as I'm adding to an existing product that uses 1.6.